# measurable subset of nonmeasurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

show that if E is measurable and E⊂P where P is nonmeasurable set in [0,1), then m(E)=0.

Can one please tell how to start ..

and I have one more question: is the union of m'ble set and non-m'ble set  m'ble? why?

(I think the union of m'ble set and non-m'ble set is non-m'ble set .but 
suppose P:=(E:=[0,1/2))∪(non measurable set in [1/2,1)) is non-m'ble
however, E⊂P is measurable s.t m(E)≠0)

Comment: Your arguement is correct. Let $A$ be a nonmeasurable set in $(\frac{1}{2},1)$, then $P:= [0,\frac{1}{2})\cup A$ is nonmeasurable. Taking $E:=[0,\frac{1}{2})$, the statement is not always true. Observe that $A= P\cap [0,\frac{1}{2})^c$ in $[0,1)$, thus if $P$ is measurable, that would imply $A$ is measurable.

Comment: The only relevant true thing that I can think of here is the following: Suppose X is non measurable and Y is measurable and there is some measurable set Z separating X and Y. Then, $X \bigcup Y$ is non measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be a non-measurable subset of the real axis $R$. The following conditions are equivalent:

(i) for each  measurable subset $E \subset P$ the condition $m(E)=0$ holds;

(ii) the inner $m$ measure of $P$ is equal to zero.